# How to automatically generate function headers for .h file in Clion?

Tags: c, refactoring, code-generation, header-files, clion

When writing a library in C, I usually end up implementing functions before defining them in the corresponding header file. As copying function header's in the header file is a repetitive task, I was wondering if I can automatically generate function headers (or even better, the full header file) in CLion?

Answer (score 19):

Maybe it's a little late (about 4 years), but here's the best way i've found (for a c file):

cut and paste the contents of the .c in the .h file, and for each function, put the cursor on it's name and press Alt+Enter, and choose "Split function into declaration and definition".

this will keep the declaration in the .h file while moving the implementation to the .c file.

hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

This only works for C++, but after you've written a function definition in a cpp file, eg:

```
void MyClass::myNewFn() { ... }
```

you can do Alt-Enter on myNewFn and select 'Create new function myNewFn()'. This will add a declaration of MyClass in the header file.

Comment: he is asking about c